# Issues with Guid on JSON serialization and deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a class which contains a property whose type is GUID.For example,

```
public class ClassToSerialize    
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

I have to pass the object from one web API to an external API. The problem is with the Guid and on serialization, the property converted to CSUUID and when deserializing it, an error is shown like 'Invalid token'.

If we remove the Id from the object on serialization, we can resolve the issue. But for this particular use case, it is not possible to remove the Id from the object.

Is there any way to pass the object without serialization?

Comment: Can you add the Newtonsoft version and an exact round-trip sample case?

Comment: Can you share the sample JSON which you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: How do you pass your object?

Comment: {"Id" : CSUUID("61d5f051-106a-4db8-83b9-1d17dd462f3c"), "Name" : "EIGHTEEN FIFTEEN_12031972_203798965_2018","Test":"Test_For_Testing"}

Comment: This is the json string gernerated.And this CSUUID is generated by mongo c# driver

Comment: `{"Id": CSUUID("61d5f051-106a-4db8-83b9-1d17dd462f3c")}` isn't well-formed JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get a parse error.  Are you sure your JSON looks like this?  If so, how did you generate it, and how are you trying to deserialize it?

Comment: its a POCO model for mongo db collection and when serializing the property of type Guid will convert to CSUUID.

Comment: *when deserializing it, an error is shown like 'Invalid token'.* - can you share your deserialization code, i.e. a [mcve]?  To `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any would also help us to suggest a way to deserialize that nonstandard JSON.